# How to display array items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ejs

Using Nodejs and ejs on the front end I have sent across an array, which has arrays inside it. However when I loop through and step into the array I'm outputted with the first item in each array rather than all the items in the array of arrays. My question is how to display all these posts? A console log shows all the posts are present just a question of how to extract them.

Below is my dummy data array and below that is a sample of the front end, any help would be grateful.

```
[ 
    [ 
        { 
            post_created_by: 'supervalue',
            post_created_by_id: 54ecb20852ea734c0598c47b,
            title: 'salmon',
            desc: '3 for 2 fresh sea salmon',
            _id: 5501b88c68e8b5842ece6eb0 
        },
        { 
            post_created_by: 'supervalue',
            post_created_by_id: 54ecb20852ea734c0598c47b,
            title: 'Milkshake',
            desc: 'Avonmore fresh strawberry milkshake 6 pack',
            _id: 5501b8fd68e8b5842ece6eb1 
         } 
    ],
    [ 
        { 
            post_created_by: 'maxol',
            post_created_by_id: 54ecb2cd52ea734c0598c47e,
            title: 'petrol',
            _id: 5501bb9168e8b5842ece6eb6 
        },
        { 
           post_created_by: 'maxol',
           post_created_by_id: 54ecb2cd52ea734c0598c47e,
           title: 'tayto',
           desc: '20 packs for the price of 12',
           _id: 5501bbb168e8b5842ece6eb7 
        } 
    ],
    [ 
        { 
            post_created_by: 'Burkes Shoes',
            post_created_by_id: 5502033d3d108e141dd01e8c,
            title: 'boots',
            desc: 'soccer boots size 5',
            _id: 5502036a3d108e141dd01e8d 
        } 
    ]
]


<% for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <a href="/busProfileFromUser?busId=<%= posts[i][0].post_created_by_id %>">
            <h5><%= posts[i][0].post_created_by %></h5>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code iterates over the outer array, but it only ever looks at the first element (the element at index 0) of the inner arrays. You need to iterate over each of those arrays in turn; a nested `for` loop is the simplest solution:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    // do something with the element at array[i][j]
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not obvious why he has a two level array.  Possibly he needs a flattening step...

Comment: In the dummy data, it looks to me like each subarray is one user's posts, in which case leaving the arrays unflattened allows any once per user code to be executed in the outer loop. Even if there is nothing to be done in this case, a flattening step doesn't provide any obvious advantage over handling the data as is.

Comment: Yeah that did it for me Andrew thanks. I tried flattening the array as Paul suggests on the server side but couldn't get it to work. Cheers folks.

Comment: I've had to switch to Paul's suggestion. I probably should have specified that the number of items in the arrays can be any number and not just two as the dummy data shows. So I've had to flatten it on the server side to bring across a simple array.

Comment: The number of elements in the subarrays shouldn't matter to either solution; what are you seeing?

Comment: It's weird, repeating some of the posts and doesn't seem to step into all of the posts. Lets say I've a total of 23 posts it will return a total of 23 but repeat some. Paul's works but trying to sort by _id isn't working as it should. Something telling me there's something else I'm missing. I'll keep at it thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the entire array of arrays into a single array using a simple recursive flatten function as follows:

```
var flattenArray = function(arr) {
    var i,
        l = arr.length,
        flatten = [],
        element,
        __push = [].push
     ;

    for(i = 0 ; i < l ; i++) {
        element = arr[i];

        if(element.constructor === Array) {
            __push.apply(flatten, flattenArray(element));
        } else {
            __push.call(flatten, element);
        }
    }

    return flatten;
};

posts = flattenArray(posts);
```

Then, use a simple for-loop to iterate over that array

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) { %>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <a href="/busProfileFromUser?busId=<%= posts[i].post_created_by_id %>">
            <h5><%= posts[i].post_created_by %></h5>
        </a>
   </div>
 <% } %>
```